# How to get file_get_contents() to work with HTTPS?

Tags: php, curl, https, file-get-contents

I'm working on setting up credit card processing and needed to use a workaround for CURL. The following code worked fine when I was using the test server (which wasn't calling an SSL URL), but now when I am testing it on the working server with HTTPS, it's failing with the error message "failed to open stream".

```
function send($packet, $url) {
  $ctx = stream_context_create(
    array(
      'http'=>array(
        'header'=>"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'method'=>'POST',
        'content'=>$packet
      )
    )
  );
  return file_get_contents($url, 0, $ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try the following script to see if there is an https wrapper available for your php scripts.

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_export($w);
```

the output should be something like

```
openssl: yes
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: yes
wrappers: array(11) {
  [...]
}
```

Comment: @volker That's why I asked for allow_url_fopen

Comment: Well what is odd is that it says openssl is off, but according to phpinfo() it is compiled with it, unless I am seeing it wrong.

Comment: phpinfo() tells you so in the configure-line or is there a whole section called "OpenSSL"?

Comment: Okay it is just in the configure-line, not a section for it.  I guess that is the problem?

Comment: I have all that and it still doesn't work. And allow_url_fopen. Only non https urls work from localhost.

Answer (score 120):

To allow https wrapper:

- the `php_openssl` extension must exist and be enabled
- `allow_url_fopen` must be set to `on`

In the php.ini file you should add this lines if not exists:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: Both are set to On in my installation but I still get the SSL error "Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: Handshake timed out in"

Answer (score 68):

If you want to be vulnerable to a man-in-the middle attack, try this code:

```
$url= 'https://example.com';

$arrContextOptions=array(
      "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    );  

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

This will allow you to get the content from the url no matter what certificate it presents

Comment: Thanks! This worked on my end. Been trying to call FB Open Graph API :)

Comment: I was trying to access a domain of mine with invalid certificate just for test purposes and even though this disables SSL validation, it was what I needed.

Comment: Great! I have been trying for 5 days to download an airbnb calendar on my XAMPP test site using file_get_contents, this solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Worked for me trying to connect to Vagrant test box without a valid HTTP certificate over https. Link to PHP SSL Context options being set here: http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php ; verify peer = Require verification of SSL certificate used; verify_peer_name=Require verification of peer name.

Comment: isn't this breaking SSL certification and is a security hole?

Comment: This is a bad Solution, youre basically disabling the SSL certification verification which allows for MITM attacks. [read more MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Answer (score 58):

Try the following.

```
function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

> Note: This disables SSL verification, meaning **the security offered
>   by HTTPS is lost**. Only use this code for testing / local
>   development, **never on the internet** or other public-facing
>   networks. If this code works, it means the SSL certificate isn't
>   trusted or can't be verified, which you should look into fixing as a
>   separate issue.

Comment: Why would you disable ssl verification when dealing with credit card processing?

Comment: Thank you, the trick is in here:     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

Answer (score 6):

Just add two lines in your php.ini file.

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

`allow_url_include = On`

its working for me.

Comment: You probably mean `allow_url_fopen` since question concerns url opening, not including.

Answer (score 5):

HTTPS is supported starting from PHP 4.3.0, if you have compiled in support for OpenSSL.
Also, make sure the target server has a valid certificate, the firewall allows outbound connections and `allow_url_fopen` in php.ini is set to true.

Comment: I have PHP 5.2.8 with OpenSSL support.  I am getting the same error with this, and the target server has a valid certificate.

Comment: is the firewall configured to allow outbound https connections? Usually, webserver running https do not run on port 80. is there anything else in the error apart from 'failed to open stream'?

Comment: As far as I know it does, this is the entire error:

Warning: fopen(https://...) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/test.php on line 993

Comment: and allow_url_fopen in php.ini is set to what?

Comment: That's odd. Can you do a GET on an HTTP and an HTTPS url to see if that works? without the stream context?

Comment: GET gives the same error as POST (going to the URL in the browser works fine).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error.  Setting `allow_url_include = On` in `php.ini` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

use the following code:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com",false,
                             stream_context_create([
                                'ssl'  => [
                                    'verify_peer'      => false,
                                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                                ]
                            ])
            );
    
 echo $homepage;
```

Comment: simple, flexible and it works!

Comment: It works for that URL from Google, but unfortunately it doesn't for mine (from the same page where the code is executed).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue was due to WAMP using a different php.ini for CLI than Apache, so your settings made through the WAMP menu don't apply to CLI. Just modify the CLI php.ini and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a server will choose not to respond based on what it sees or doesn't see in the http request headers (such as an appropriate user agent). If you can connect with a browser, grab the headers it sends and mimic them in your stream context.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with non functional https on IIS. Solved with:

file_get_contents('https.. ) wouldn't load.

- download https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
- install under ..phpN.N/extras/ssl
- edit php.ini with:

  curl.cainfo = "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
  openssl.cafile="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

finally!