# Cant open a https website with php and fopen

Tags: php, https, fopen

I am using fopen to retreive the contents of a URL.
It works on http URLs but not https URLs

Can anyone see why??

```
<?php

//this works fine
echo ("<br><br>url 1 is ".OutputURL("http://nuenergy.acornsoftware.com.au/staff/interface/index.php"));

//returns nothing
echo ("<br><br>url 2 is ".OutputURL("https://nuenergy.acornsoftware.com.au/staff/interface/index.php"));

function OutputURL($url)
{
  $handle = fopen($url, "r");
  $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
  fclose($handle);
  return $contents;
}
//
?>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as I'm not to look further into an answer as of this moment. Hope you find some help!

Comment: Is your php_openssl.dll enabled in apache?

Comment: See related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/filegetcontents-with-https

Answer (score 5):

You need to have OpenSSL installed and configured with PHP, I recommend you ask this on [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com/).

Also, you can just use `file_get_contents()` instead of `OutputURL()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with PHP not returning anything for HTTPS, it's your file not outputting anything for the HTTPS version of the file. When I view the HTTP version, it outputs a small XML diagram representing some sort of 'File Not Found' error. When I view the HTTPS form of the file, it returns a blank page, absolutely no content in the source code. You need to look at your Apache configurations and make sure it's pointing to all the files properly.

Answer (score 0):

It'll either be that your apache/php setup does not support https via fopen or your server's firewall has blocked this type of connection.