# how to get contents of site use HTTPS

Tags: php, curl, https, fopen

ex of site using ssl ( HTTPs ) : https://www.eb2a.com

1 - i tried to get its content using file_get_contents, but not work and **give error**
ex :

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("https://www.eb2a.com/");

echo $contents;
?>
```

2 - i tried to use fopen, but not work and **give error**
ex:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.eb2a.com/';
$contents = fopen($url, 'r');
echo "$contents";
?>
```

3 - i tried to use CURL, but not work and give **BLANK PAGE**
ex :

```
function cURL($url, $ref, $header, $cookie, $p){
$ch =  curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    
if ($p) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
}
$result =  curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($result){
    return $result;
}else{
    return '';
}
}

$file = cURL('https://www.eb2a.com/','https://www.eb2a.com/',0,0,null);
echo $file
```

any one have any idea ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [file_get_contents with https?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https)

Comment: You have the answer here: [how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https)

Comment: You may enable openssl extension in the php.ini as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880176/1054582

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the contents from secure protocal `https`, you need to have `openssl` extenstion enabled from php.ini file and the authentication for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

web site redirect 301

change url

from

```
https://www.eb2a.com/
```

to

```
https://www.eb2a.com
```

or if still not working or need use it with /

loook at [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233771/php-curl-function-301-error)

use curl redirect rules