# Get file content from URL?

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

When I use following URL in browser then it prompt me to download a text file with JSOn content.

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World&chof=json

***(Click above URL see downloaded file content)***

Now I want to create a php page. I want that when I call this php page, it should call above URL and get content(json format) from file and show it on screen.

How can I do this ??

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Depending on your PHP configuration, this *may* be a easy as using:

```
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World&chof=json'));
```

However, if `allow_url_fopen` isn't enabled on your system, you could read the data via CURL as follows:

```
<?php
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World&chof=json');
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
    curl_close($curlSession);
?>
```

Incidentally, if you just want the raw JSON data, then simply remove the `json_decode`.

Comment: Thank you voted up :) edit: I tried without json_decode and got a fully rendered url but with decode, nothing. What is the purpose of decode?

Comment: @Steven It decodes JSON string into a PHP variable.

Comment: @John_Parker many thanks. I'm currently using Google to render a snapshot of a url but it's not ideal as the image is small but with JSON decode as a PHP variable, is this an array I can split and grab things like a page title and the first image? Cheers.

Comment: From PHP 5.1.3, BINARYTRANSFER option has no effect: the raw output will always be returned when CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is used.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 25):

1) **local simplest methods**

```
<?php
echo readfile("http://example.com/");   //needs "Allow_url_include" enabled
//OR
echo include("http://example.com/");    //needs "Allow_url_include" enabled
//OR
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/");
//OR
echo stream_get_contents(fopen('http://example.com/', "rb")); //you may use "r" instead of "rb"  //needs "Allow_url_fopen" enabled
?>
```

2) **Better Way is CURL**:

```
echo get_remote_data('http://example.com'); // GET request 
echo get_remote_data('http://example.com', "var2=something&var3=blabla" ); // POST request
```

It automatically handles **FOLLOWLOCATION** problem  + Remote urls: 
 `src="./imageblabla.png"` turned into:
`src="http://example.com/path/imageblabla.png"`

Code : https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/get-remote-url-content-data.php

Comment: sorry how do I call it with REPLACESSOURCES = True?

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget: to get HTTPS contents, your OPENSSL extension should be enabled in your php.ini. ([how to get contents of site use HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880169/how-to-get-contents-of-site-use-https))

Answer (score 3):

Use `file_get_contents` in combination with `json_decode` and `echo`.

Comment: I am using file_get_contents to get Content but it is not JSON when I echo it. It is showing some special characters.

Comment: @Awan were you ever able to figure this out? I'm also seeing special characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = "https://chart.googleapis....";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

Now you can either echo the $json variable, if you just want to display the output, or you can decode it, and do something with it, like so:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```