# How to Parse a Web page using PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I am Learning php. I have learned some basics. Now I am eager to learn Web page parsing.
I want to Parse this page http://www.icc-cricket.com/rankings/team-rankings/test 
I want to parse this alone
Rank Team Matches Points Rating
1 South Africa 24 3240 135

Comment: With [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get file content from a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522636/get-file-content-from-a-url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522636/get-file-content-from-a-url

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Symfony2 The DomCrawler Component http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know basic PHP, I would recommend you using this framework: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Its simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ which allows you to parse HTML pages rather easily.

That said, one should always instead look into if the service offers feeds instead, because parsing them are both less error prone, more efficient and (usually) don't change much. HTML-markup can change over time, causing your dom query to become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that those scores are attached to pages via ajax. So you cannot parse this link directly to get your rankings. It seems that request is sent to 
http://cma.icc-cricket.com/api/getRankings?callback=onRankings&_1375776810417=

So you need to make similar request and process data then.
Result from url:

```
onRankings([{"matchType":"TEST","rankings":[{"position":"1","team":{"fullName":"South Africa","abbreviation":"SA"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"24","points":"3240","rating":"135"},{"position":"2","team":{"fullName":"India","abbreviation":"IND"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"30","points":"3473","rating":"116"},{"position":"3","team":{"fullName":"England","abbreviation":"ENG"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"32","points":"3577","rating":"112"},{"position":"4","team":{"fullName":"Australia","abbreviation":"AUS"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"27","points":"2846","rating":"105"},{"position":"5","team":{"fullName":"Pakistan","abbreviation":"PAK"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"19","points":"1947","rating":"102"},{"position":"6","team":{"fullName":"West Indies","abbreviation":"WI"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"22","points":"2168","rating":"99"},{"position":"7","team":{"fullName":"Sri Lanka","abbreviation":"SL"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"26","points":"2295","rating":"88"},{"position":"8","team":{"fullName":"New Zealand","abbreviation":"NZ"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"27","points":"2126","rating":"79"},{"position":"9","team":{"fullName":"Bangladesh","abbreviation":"BAN"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"13","points":"135","rating":"10"}]},{"matchType":"ODI","rankings":[{"position":"1","team":{"fullName":"India","abbreviation":"IND"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"48","points":"5906","rating":"123"},{"position":"2","team":{"fullName":"Australia","abbreviation":"AUS"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"34","points":"3861","rating":"114"},{"position":"3","team":{"fullName":"England","abbreviation":"ENG"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"38","points":"4257","rating":"112"},{"position":"4","team":{"fullName":"Sri Lanka","abbreviation":"SL"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"49","points":"5435","rating":"111"},{"position":"5","team":{"fullName":"South Africa","abbreviation":"SA"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"34","points":"3584","rating":"105"},{"position":"6","team":{"fullName":"Pakistan","abbreviation":"PAK"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"42","points":"4294","rating":"102"},{"position":"7","team":{"fullName":"New Zealand","abbreviation":"NZ"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"29","points":"2593","rating":"89"},{"position":"8","team":{"fullName":"West Indies","abbreviation":"WI"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"41","points":"3639","rating":"89"},{"position":"9","team":{"fullName":"Bangladesh","abbreviation":"BAN"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"23","points":"1754","rating":"76"},{"position":"10","team":{"fullName":"Zimbabwe","abbreviation":"ZIM"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"23","points":"1205","rating":"52"},{"position":"11","team":{"fullName":"Ireland","abbreviation":"IRE"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"10","points":"394","rating":"39"},{"position":"12","team":{"fullName":"Netherlands","abbreviation":"NL"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"7","points":"88","rating":"13"},{"position":"13","team":{"fullName":"Kenya","abbreviation":"KEN"},"qfyMatches":"0","played":"4","points":"40","rating":"10"}]},{"matchType":"T20I","rankings":[{"position":"1","team":{"fullName":"Sri Lanka","abbreviation":"SL"},"qfyMatches":"20","played":"16","points":"2003","rating":"125"},{"position":"2","team":{"fullName":"Pakistan","abbreviation":"PAK"},"qfyMatches":"31","played":"21","points":"2599","rating":"124"},{"position":"3","team":{"fullName":"India","abbreviation":"IND"},"qfyMatches":"18","played":"14","points":"1689","rating":"121"},{"position":"5","team":{"fullName":"South Africa","abbreviation":"SA"},"qfyMatches":"24","played":"18","points":"2158","rating":"120"},{"position":"4","team":{"fullName":"West Indies","abbreviation":"WI"},"qfyMatches":"22","played":"17","points":"2041","rating":"120"},{"position":"6","team":{"fullName":"England","abbreviation":"ENG"},"qfyMatches":"26","played":"19","points":"2148","rating":"113"},{"position":"7","team":{"fullName":"Australia","abbreviation":"AUS"},"qfyMatches":"23","played":"17","points":"1753","rating":"103"},{"position":"8","team":{"fullName":"New Zealand","abbreviation":"NZ"},"qfyMatches":"25","played":"19","points":"1937","rating":"102"},{"position":"unranked","team":{"fullName":"Afghanistan","abbreviation":"AFG"},"qfyMatches":"7","played":"6","points":"525","rating":"88"},{"position":"9","team":{"fullName":"Ireland","abbreviation":"IRE"},"qfyMatches":"12","played":"7","points":"568","rating":"81"},{"position":"10","team":{"fullName":"Bangladesh","abbreviation":"BAN"},"qfyMatches":"14","played":"10","points":"739","rating":"74"},{"position":"11","team":{"fullName":"Scotland","abbreviation":"Sco"},"qfyMatches":"9","played":"7","points":"435","rating":"62"},{"position":"12","team":{"fullName":"Zimbabwe","abbreviation":"ZIM"},"qfyMatches":"14","played":"10","points":"478","rating":"48"},{"position":"13","team":{"fullName":"Netherlands","abbreviation":"NL"},"qfyMatches":"8","played":"5","points":"181","rating":"36"},{"position":"14","team":{"fullName":"Kenya","abbreviation":"KEN"},"qfyMatches":"11","played":"9","points":"309","rating":"34"},{"position":"unranked","team":{"fullName":"Canada","abbreviation":"CAN"},"qfyMatches":"6","played":"4","points":"24","rating":"6"}]}]);
```

But if you want to just learn HTML parsing then you can allso use [Ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/)

Answer (score 0):

As per my view its not possible to parse, because that table is appending through AJAX calls.
We can see a empty tag like this:

```
<section class="standings"></section>
```

If I have this all wrong, please correct me

Thanks