# using Exclamation in php file_get_contents

Tags: php

I am trying to pass across a string to receive a response. In the URL, at the end for the Password= field, there is a Exclamation Point in the string. This is causing a fail in the code - I have included an example below

```
$getResponse    = file_get_contents("https://LINK/&Password=pass!word");
echo "<br>Response:";var_dump($getResponse);die;
```

I have tried both as you see above AND by putting \ in front of the Exclamation Point. Any assistance would be greatly apprecieated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620810/how-to-retrieve-the-data-from-a-url-with-an-exclamation-mark-inside-it

Comment: That URL looks weird. Are you sure you're not missing something? Like a `?` at some point? That URL would actually look for a resource called `&Password=pass!word`, not sending Password as a parameter.

Comment: To keep the question simple I did remove a tonne of data. Yes you are correct it should have a ? at the start but for the purpose of this question it was not needed.

Comment: Then you have your answer below. `urlencode()` is the solution.

Comment: Not related to `file_get_contents()` in any way. You fail to build a properly encoded URL. Always use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to properly encode the dynamic data when you build an URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode non-ASCII characters (!) into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.

Try this:

```
    $url=urlencode("https://LINK/&Password=pass!word");
    $getResponse    = file_get_contents($url);
    echo "Response:";var_dump($getResponse);die;
```

[Urlencode Help on PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping password in url:

```
$pswd = urlencode('pass!word'); /* or use - rawurlencode */
$url = 'https://example.com/page?Password='.$pswd; /* replaced `&` with `?` */
$getResponse = file_get_contents($url);
```