# unresolved warning message when running php script: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https"

Tags: ssl, openssl, fopen, php

I am running php 5.2.17 on windows 7
php is running through the command line and not on a server.

I was getting the following error message

```
C:\java\newsweaver-api-v2\simple>php list-tags.php

Notice: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget
 to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\java\newsweaver-api-v2\simple\list-
tags.php on line 30
```

so I downloaded OpenSSL windows binaries
http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

And I downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyid=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF&displaylang=en

I read elsewhere that I needed to change ;extension=php_openssl.dll to extension=php_openssl.dll in my php.ini file put my php file does not contain

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I tried running the php file again after making these changes and I am getting the same error msg.

```
Notice: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget
to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
[How to get file_get_contents() to work with HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https)

Comment: Hi ya I ran that and got the following output                        C:\java\php>php phptest.php
openssl: no
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: no
wrappers: array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "file"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "data"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "http"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "ftp"
  [5]=>
  string(13) "compress.zlib"
}

Comment: As long as you don't have OpenSSL enabled it will not work. Did ypu add extension=php_openssl.dll to php.ini?

Comment: Thanks for replying Im running wamp on windows 7 ya I have edited the php.ini in the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin directory like you said and also set the source directory for extentions to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext and after doing the openssl is still not enabled?

Comment: the following link seems promising about setting up openssl in wamp I hoping these steps work http://www.neubreed.com.au/blog/2008/07/enabling_and_configuring_ssl_apache_22_under_windows_wamp_server_2