# file_get_contents script works with some websites but not others

Tags: php, regex, parsing, file-get-contents

I'm looking to build a PHP script that parses HTML for particular tags.  I've been using this code block, adapted from this [tutorial](http://www.oooff.com/php-scripts/basic-php-scraped-data-parsing/basic-php-data-parsing.php):

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$regex = '/<title>(.+?)</';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match); 
echo $match[1];
?>
```

The script works with some websites (like google, above), but when I try it with other websites (like, say, freshdirect), I get this error:

"Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.freshdirect.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"

I've seen a bunch of great [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836566/unresolved-warning-message-when-running-php-script-file-get-contents-unable-t) on StackOverflow, for example to enable `extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini.  But (1) my version of php.ini didn't have `extension=php_openssl.dll` in it, and (2) when I added it to the extensions section and restarted the WAMP server, per this [thread](http://www.leoganda.net/how-to-enable-xampp-ssl-socket-transport/), still no success.

Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe have a look at curl like on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697472/file-get-contents-returning-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_html('http://google.com/');
$title = $html->find('title')->innertext;
```

Or if you prefer with preg_match and you should be really using cURL instead of fgc...

```
function curl($url){

    $headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
    $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
    $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
    $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;

}


$data = curl('http://www.google.com');
$regex = '#<title>(.*?)</title>#mis';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match); 
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Only use simple html dom if you don't have the choice between [swaths of faster alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Wrikken, faster in what sense?

Comment: DOM parsing, and searching / altering the DOM in general (but it can be somewhat verbose to do actual alterations if one it not used to DOM, hence the link to an answer with packages that make it as easy as simplehtmldom, but still use dom/libxml for faster processing).

Comment: @Wrikken, I modified simplehtmldom to use cURL in order to fetch pages faster, but haven't really payed attention for processing speed. I use regex, even though it is not how is "meant to be played". Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 5):

It just requires a user-agent ("any" really, any string suffices):

```
file_get_contents("http://www.freshdirect.com",false,stream_context_create(
    array("http" => array("user_agent" => "any"))
));
```

See [more options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

Of course, you can set [`user_agent`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent) in your ini:

```
 ini_set("user_agent","any");
 echo file_get_contents("http://www.freshdirect.com");
```

... but I prefer to be explicit for the next programmer working on it.

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you!

Comment: Why do some website require this, btw?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Naive WAF and/or custom responses for some user-agents. However, as https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.43 states, you should use a user-agent (although not required), it's always a good idea to follow the shoulds in an RFC.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Some hosts disable `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` so recursive is what you want, also will log into a text file any errors. Also a simple example of how to use `DOMDocument()` to extract the content, obviously its not extensive but something you could build appon.

```
<?php 
function file_get_site($url){
(function_exists('curl_init')) ? '' : die('cURL Must be installed. Ask your host to enable it or uncomment extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini');
$curl = curl_init();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0 Firefox/5.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

$html = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($status['http_code']!=200){
    if($status['http_code'] == 301 || $status['http_code'] == 302) {
        list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $html, 2);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match("/(Location:|URI:)[^(\n)]*/", $header, $matches);
        $url = trim(str_replace($matches[1],"",$matches[0]));
        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        return (isset($url_parsed))? file_get_site($url):'';
    }
    $oline='';
    foreach($status as $key=>$eline){$oline.='['.$key.']'.$eline.' ';}
    $line =$oline." \r\n ".$url."\r\n-----------------\r\n";
    $handle = @fopen('./curl.error.log', 'a');
    fwrite($handle, $line);
    return FALSE;
}
return $html;
}


function get_content_tags($source,$tag,$id=null,$value=null){
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    @$xml->loadHTML($source);

    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName($tag) as $tags) {
        if($id!=null){
            if($tags->getAttribute($id)==$value){
                return $tags->getAttribute('content');
            }
        }
        return $tags->nodeValue;
    }
}


$source = file_get_site('http://www.freshdirect.com/about/index.jsp');

echo get_content_tags($source,'title'); //FreshDirect

echo get_content_tags($source,'meta','name','description'); //Online grocer providing high quality fresh......

?>
```