# how to stop & from changing to &amp in a url?

Tags: php, url, htmlspecialchars

I have a url like this, `https://www.example.com/send?id=1`&`text=http://example2.com/song.mp3`

when I try to get the data of the url using `file_get_contents()` it shows below error,

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(`https://www.example.com/send?id=1`&amp`text=http://example2.com/song.mp3`):
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented

and the & have converted to &amp. due to that the url is not working.

I have tried `htmlspecialchars_decode()` and `preg_replace()` on & , but it didn't do anything.

how to solve this ?

Comment: @Xorifelse no escaping it with %26 did not solve the problem

Comment: referring url is http or https?

Comment: try using curl, I posted below & hope it will work

Comment: is it working now?

Answer (score 1):

I think you better to use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) instead of `file_get_contents()`, because referring server must be enabled [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in their server if you are using `file_get_contents()`, but cURL is a library it just make a http requests

```
<?php
    $cSession = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.example.com/send?id=1&text=http://example2.com/song.mp3");
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    $result=curl_exec($cSession);
    curl_close($cSession);
    echo $result;
?>
```

refer following links

[file_get_contents script works with some websites but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902955/file-get-contents-script-works-with-some-websites-but-not-others)

[cURL vs file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php)

Comment: There seems to be a space before and after the '&' in the url. You can try to remove the spaces

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this sir, where $str="your link"

sample

```
$str = "https://www.example.com/send?id=1&text=http://example2.com/song.mp3";

echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

will output the one you want....