# Retrieving info from JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, json

i have this public JSON https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json and i need to extract data from it, right now i tried something like this:

```
$input = file_get_contents("https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json");

$json = json_decode($input);

echo $json[rates]->EUR;
```

but i obtain a blank page, any suggestion? Thanks !! Ste

Comment: Did you already try `$json->rates->EUR`?

Answer (score 6):

`json_decode` either returns an object, or an array (when you use the second param). You are trying to use both.

Try:

```
$json = json_decode($input);    
echo $json->rates->EUR;
```

OR

```
$json = json_decode($input, true);
echo $json['rates']['EUR'];
```

---

As to the blank page, please add the following to the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
init_set('display_errors', true);
```

---

A 500 Error indicates you are unable to resolve that url using file_get_contents.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https) for more information.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for answers, but remains the same, blank page :/

Comment: Please see my update, could solve your white screen of death.

Answer (score 0):

The link looks like starting with https, while [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can't deal with SSL. My suggestion is using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: file_get_contents CAN deal with those links if PHP was built with ssl, or if you've written and registered your own https stream

Answer (score 0):

Read the help for [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) ... without the second parameter it returns and object not an array ...

Either :

```
$json = json_decode($input);
echo $json->rates->EUR;
```

or

```
$json = json_decode($input,true);
echo $json['rates']['EUR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$arr = json_decode($input, true);

var_dump($arr);
echo $arr['rates']['EUR'];
```

Further Reading:
http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

For anexample with cURL and SSL read this:
http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: it gives "NULL", don't know why :)

Comment: Then you get no result from file_get_contents().
Try cURL instead

Comment: can you give me an example with cURL? i'm looking for info but im a little bit confused, thanks:)

Comment: This method is explained here:
http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/