# Codeigniter file_get_content() error permission using https protocol

Tags: php, codeigniter, https, download

I use the codeigniter framework, i put a script in the controller to force download an existing text file in some folder. the connection use the protocol HTTPS.when i click to download the text file from the server , an error has been occurred , it's below:

```
Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
Filename: controllers/process.php
```

when i print `"var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());"` that gives a result like that:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "file"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "glob"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "data"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "http"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "ftp"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "compress.zlib"
  [7]=>
  string(14) "compress.bzip2"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "phar"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "zip"
}
```

so no https wrapper exist in the array.

how proceed to resolve that?

Thank you for any suggestion...

Comment: A quick serch on THIS website shoud help you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=file_get_contents+with+https

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have access for https protocol.

Try this [How to get file_get_contents() to work with HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https)

Or use curl or sockets

Comment: Thank you . How that's can be used?curl with https??

Comment: i check it, i re-edit the question below, u can see what's happen when i try to use:var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `php_openssl.dll` or `php_openssl.so`  is enabled.