# PHP: file_get_contents function does not work in graph api facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve facebook uesr ID via graph from below code

```
$post =  "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$access_token;
$response = file_get_contents($post);
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: /me cannot be read [file_get_contents] https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=AAIvGrJsBAI3nLAbfaqyh8NExN5e21yKCvJAjVOGJ9ira1RdCDHRFszktHnDCY44urQtxdBHMKEsX1K7QAUWXSYF5ip3l68JI8xKeopjYdssds

But when i try to access the above graph URL via browser, its working correctly. So my access token is valid.

Note: I am using google app engine so I can't use cURL.

Comment: result comes in `json` so try with `json_decode($response)`

Comment: If you take a look at the responce in your browser (using google chrome f12 -> network tab) you will see, that the headers have Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error. If that is correct - I'll move my comment to the answer section.

Comment: @Дамян and how does that answer the question? OP is looking for a solution.

Comment: yea how does that answer that question

Comment: this is cross domain data exchange. use `CURL` or `jsonp`

Comment: file_get_contents() assumes failure when you get that status. Use cURL.

Comment: @Дамян and? the question would still be: why does that error occur in the first place and how to fix it.

Comment: hey diecho , I use google app engine , so curl and jsonp is not possible if am not wrong :|

Comment: Simple - Use cURL or some other class with good error/status handling.

Comment: i think file_get_contents not work with HTTPS look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https   Or use curl ( and be sure of curl ( faster ) with https )

Answer (score 1):

Use cURL or this class: http://ideone.com/Q1Zfl

I've used this class many times and it behaves well.

Usage:

```
$url = '...';
$req = new Request($url);
$data = $req->DownloadToString();
```

P.S I hope the link does not expire

Comment: How about the other class I gave you?

Comment: Can't think of a different way. cURL or some class like this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> $content = @file_get_contents($site);

To hide the error. If it's dont work. You go to the ini.php file and find the line

> Allow_url_fopen = Off

Change "off" to "on"

> Allow_url_fopen = On