# wsdl connection in PHP

Tags: php, wsdl

I have a bizarre situation where I can get the URL 
$wsdl = 'https://www.connectwebservice.com/sandbox1_test/services/IR?wsdl over a normal web browser URL buy putting the path into the URL bar, but I cannot seem to connect via also `file_get_contents()` does not return anything, though the same code works fine on other connections.

I have built some error diagnostic code if this will help anyone in the future...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 120);  
ini_set("track_errors","On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$days = 7;  
$date = date('d/m/Y 00:00', (time() - ($days * 24 * 60 * 60))); 

$soap_args = array(
    'exceptions'=>true,
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'=>true,
    'connection_timeout'=>120,
    );

$wsdl = 'https://www.connectwebservice.com/sandbox1_test/services/IR?wsdl'; 

if(file_get_contents($wsdl)){

    try {

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$soap_args);

        $product = $client->getProductIdsChangedSinceDateStrForType(array("lastRequestDateStr" => $date, "leafOnly" => true))->getProductIdsChangedSinceDateStrForTypeReturn;       

    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        var_dump(libxml_get_last_error());
        ?><br/><br/><pre><?php var_dump($fault); ?></pre><?php
        echo "<br/><br/>----------------------<br/><br/>";
        echo "Reason:   ";
        trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);

    }

    //show results if posible

    if($client){


        if ($product != '') { 
            $product = split(',', $product); 
            ?>Products:<br/><br/><pre><?php print_r($productIds); ?></pre><?php
            echo "<br/><br/>----------------------<br/><br/>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "$client only?";           
    }

    ?><br/><br/>Client:<br/><br/><pre><?php print_r($client); ?></pre>

    <?php

} else {
    echo "<br/>no connection or bad url";
}
```

`

Comment: Why are you trying to pull it as a file?  Your should be able to simply pull the information back through the SoapClient instead

Comment: Perhaps connecting with HTTPS from PHP needs something like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https

Answer (score 0):

Check if `allow-url-fopen` is set to `true` in the `php.ini`

http://es2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen