# PHP file get content error

Tags: php, facebook, file-get-contents

In the following code i get error `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`

```
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$orderId";
        $url_with_token = $url . "?access_token=$token";
        $result= json_decode(file_get_contents($url_with_token));
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: please check the token.

Comment: may be something wrong with `$orderId` or `$token`? Print `$url_with_token` before and see whats there.

Comment: When I paste `$url_with_token` in browser, I get correct result

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https

Answer (score 0):

Just add two lines in your php.ini file.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_include = On
```

its working for me.