# Which PHP function should one use to open files on a server?

Tags: php, file, fopen, readfile

I want to open a file on a remote server (e.g. `http://example.org/script.php?param=000001`). PHP provides several of those methods and I was wondering which method I should take and why? Are there any advantages/disadvantages?

So far I used `fopen()`, but after several reading-operations it happens that the server did not answer my request and fopen() failed. Afterwards I tried `file_get_contents()`, which also failed.

I thought it might be the server that blocked my IP, since I opened to many streams. **Could this also happen with `file_get_contents()`?**

Which method should I use, When I want to open many files on a server?

**What is the technical difference between `fopen()` and `file_get_contents()`?** And why should the server block my IP? (e.g. servers have limited number of open file streams,... or fopen needs more ressources)

Comment: By "many" do you mean "many simultaneous" or "many, one after another"?

Comment: You can't "open a file" on a server using HTTP. You can make an HTTP request and the server will (may) provide a response.

Comment: Local file: all of the method you've mentioned are fine. Remote file: [cURL](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is the way to go

If you have special HTTP header requirements, use the [context param](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)

Update:

I see that you have edited the question a little bit. Note, that the difference between `fopen` and `file_get_contents` is only that the latter will open the file, read contents, close file, return the contents where the first just opens the file. The process of *opening* is the same.

Comment: +1. If you wanna use file_get_contents() with https, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https