# HTTPS error CodeIgniter Twitter REST API

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, twitter

How do I fix this HTTPS error?

I was trying to learn how to use [Twitter's REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) with CodeIgniter when I encountered the following error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to
>   find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you
>   configured PHP?
>
> Filename: controllers/search.php
>
> Line Number: 36
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning

```
$a = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?@stackexchange'), true);
        var_dump($a);
```

> [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> Filename: controllers/search.php
>
> Line Number: 36

with the following code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {           
        $a = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?@stackexchange'), true);
        var_dump($a);

        //$this->load->view('search_page');
    }
}

/* End of file search.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/search.php */
```

Comment: Did you check to see if you have SSL support compiled/enabled for PHP? Run `phpinfo();` to see.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will also need to make sure that `php_openssl`, `.dll or .so`  based on your OS is enabled..