# Trying to get property of non-object,reverse geocoding with Google maps in Cakephp

Tags: php, google-maps, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x i have implemented the google maps successfully by using google map helper 
here

https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper

now i am trying to get the formatted address on the basis of lattitude and langtitude

i am doing this

```
 $url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?  latlng=$latitude,$longitude&sensor=true";


$json = @file_get_contents($url);


$data=json_decode($json);


$status = $data->status;

if($status=="OK"){
    $address = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
}
```

it is giving me the error that

Trying to get property of non-object on line this

```
   $status = $data->status;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the whitespace before `latlng` doesn't exists in your original code(when it does, remove it):

The server needs to support SSL when you request a ressource via HTTPS(see [How to get file_get_contents() to work with HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https) ) .

You may either enable the SSL-support or request the file via HTTP instead:

```
$url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$latitude,$longitude&sensor=true";
//---------^  remove the s from https
```