# Flex4.6 Security error accessing url when using an xml created by script.google.com

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, twitter, flash-builder

First off all im not the best programmer i have some good basics of java/php and some others.

I'm creating an application in Flash Builder 4.6 and wanted to get my twitter tweets in there.
So im using Twitter Rss Generator on script.google.com to create an RSS feed of my twitter tweets this creates a url where i add my twitter id and i get an Rss feed of my tweets.

My main is :

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="myRss" url="assets/php/Twitter.rss.php" showBusyCursor="true" resultFormat="e4x" method="GET" result="myRss_resultHandler(event)" fault="myRss_faultHandler(event)" />
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        [Bindable]
        private var feedData: XMLListCollection;

        protected function myRss_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var rssFeed:XML = XML(event.result);
            feedData = new XMLListCollection(XMLList(rssFeed.channel.item.title));

        }

        protected function myRss_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(event.fault.faultString, event.fault.faultCode);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:List id="feedItems"
        dataProvider="{feedData}"
        labelField="title"
        width="100 %" height="100 %"
        />
```

Now here is the problem i tried to do a normal call with Https service but it told me Security error accesing url. Then i tried to use php to get around that like this:

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);


$source_base = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxLK-     DUudR1bidui6myeg107gmf25ixEy5u1KA836iJKigzxqts/exec?367233361829306369";

$xmlstr_rss = file_get_contents(trim($source_base));
$sxml_rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr_rss);
$output = $sxml_rss->asXML(); // asXML();
echo $output; // naar scherm printen
```

This is what i see then plus the errors off course:

```
openssl: no http wrapper: yes https wrapper: no wrappers:

array
 0 => string 'php' (length=3)
 1 => string 'file' (length=4)
 2 => string 'glob' (length=4)
 3 => string 'data' (length=4)
 4 => string 'http' (length=4)
 5 => string 'ftp' (length=3)
 6 => string 'zip' (length=3)
 7 => string 'compress.zlib' (length=13)
 8 => string 'phar' (length=4)
```

But it gives me this error :

> Error #1088
>
> Then i went and checked my local host and went to the php in question
>   and i get those errors:
>
> " Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to
>   find the wrapper "https"
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could
>   not be parsed as XML'  and two more about the same thing

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you talking about Adobe/Apache Flex the UI Framework?  The code you have provided does not look like ActionScript3 code.  Based on the error you've provided; it doesn't look like a security error.  What is the code behind `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: PHP question: see [file\_get\_contents with https?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https)