# file_get_contents working in HTTP but not under HTTPS

Tags: php, arrays, function, http, https

```
$newLogUrl = SERVER URL PATH
$opt = array('http' => array(
             'method'  => "POST",
             'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
             'content' => $jsonCredenObj,
             'timeout' => 4));
$context = stream_context_create($opt);

$response = file_get_contents($newLogUrl,false,$context);
```

The above code is working in the normal http but not working in the secure server https

The Error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: POssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https

Comment: did you read the error? You're not allowed to do post to that url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 405 Method Not Allowed

> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the
>   resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an
>   Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested
>   resource.
>   Also as [**`MarcB`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) mentioned , the corresponding URL you are connecting does not accept the `POST` method.

[`Source : www.w3.org`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Always check the URL for headers to see what methods they accept and etc.. you could make use `$http_response_header` for that..

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://thatremoteurl.com');
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

---

### Working with HTTPs URLs

You need to enable `openssl` extension on your PHP.ini.

Open your PHP.ini and check for this line `;extension=php_openssl.dll` . Remove the semicolon before it and save your file and restart your webserver.