# Google App Engine (PHP) - file_get_contents with URL returns false

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm using google app engine locally and the request returns what it should.

Then I try on google app engine (the appspot service myapp.appspot.com) and the exact same call simply returns false without any errors.

The php documentation says I should get an error or a warning but I really don't see anything.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

I found this gae php documentation below but I really can't figure out what could be wrong.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/

I'm trying to fetch an url of another app from the appspot and the gae doc says:

> Making requests to another App Engine app
>
> If you are making requests to another App Engine app, you should
>   consider telling the URL Fetch service to not follow redirects when
>   invoking it.

Does anyone know how do I do that, or maybe what could even be the real problem ?

Here is my snippet:

```
    $content = file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
    if (false === $content) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        throw new ClientException($error['message']);
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

Here is my php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, php_uname, getmypid"
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "storage_bucket_name"
allow_url_include=1
allow_url_fopen=1
```

I tried with the following code:

```
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $content = file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
    if (false === $content) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        throw new ClientException($error['message']);
    }
```

Now I get this error: "failed to open stream: Invalid headers. Must be a string."

This is my $context variable which is passed through stream_context_create():
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.stream-context-create.php

```
array(2) {
  ["http"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["method"]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["header"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["content"]=>
    NULL
    ["protocol_version"]=>
    float(1)
    ["ignore_errors"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["max_redirects"]=>
    int(5)
    ["timeout"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["ssl"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["verify_peer"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

This is leading me to that old thread:

[Using file_get_contents invalid headers issue on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071860/using-file-get-contents-invalid-headers-issue-on-gae)

Comment: do you have warnings enabled? is `allow_url_fopen` enabled?

Comment: I updated my answer, the error shows: failed to open stream: Invalid headers. Must be a string

Comment: Have you tried not supplying $context to file_get_contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had the error "failed to open stream: Invalid headers. Must be a string." I focused on the header part of the context.

The $context['http']['headers'] was obviously a string(0) ""

I tried to unset the $context['http']['headers'] if it was empty and the problem is solved.

Note: this happens only in Google App Engine (GAE)