# How to send ajax post with specific options using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, https, jsonp

I need to send data to another domain. Now I use jquery and ajax

```
var post_data = {
   foo: "foo",
   bar: "bar"
};

jQuery.ajax({
   url:"https://notmydomain.com/polling/?d=jsonp",
   crossDomain:true,
   dataType:"jsonp",
   cache:false,
   data: post_data,
   type: "post"
});
```

It works fine, but I need to send it using php.
Try to use this solution:

```
$post_data = http_build_query(
  array(
    'foo' => 'foo',
    'bar' => 'bar'
  )
);

$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $post_data
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://notmydomain.com/polling/?d=jsonp', false, $context);
```

But it's not work. I'm think cause of specific options in ajax like:

```
crossDomain:true,
dataType:"jsonp",
cache:false
```

Don't know how to solve it, need help!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use cURL?

Comment: ajax is just http. what you're doing is a plain old http request. ajax is specifically for browser->server requests. server->server isn't ajax.

Comment: I just tried your code, changing the url to point to a local php file, and it looks like it worked for me. I suspect it has something to do with your server not being able to make https request because the ssl wrapper is not enabled. Can you do it with http instead and print out the content of $result.

Comment: [This might help you if it is indeed the ssl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https). There is a answer that has 81 upvotes that shows how to enable the extension.