# Need to parse a photo with DuckDuckGo

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $get = file_get_contents("https://duckduckgo.com/i.js?q=love&s=1");
    $decode = json_decode($get, TRUE);
    foreach($decode['results'] as $res) {
        echo "".$res['image']."";
    }
?>
```

Nothing happens. What's wrong?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://duckduckgo.com/i.js?q=love&s=1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home01/rfep/nzfrka/home/mydomain/myfeed/sssfi.php on line 2
```

**failed to open stream**

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home01/rfep/nzfrka/home/mydomain/myfeed/sssfi.php on line 4
```

Comment: `echo "<img src='" . $res['image'] . "' style='width:100px' /><br/>";`  try this.. its working.. and showing the images as well

Comment: Why do you have `echo "".$res['image']."";` There is not need for those quotes, you can just do `echo $res['image'];`.

Comment: You're probably getting an error message but you haven't configured your development box to report it.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: The code is somewhat crude, but it successfully extracts the image urls from the reply. Question is why apparently this does not appear to be working for you... It _mighty_ be that `"file_get_contents()` is blocked for external urls on your system.

Comment: Everyone here, provided you answer to our questions...

Comment: file_get_contents - successfully working on my website

Comment: echo "<img src='{$res['image']}' height='200px' width='300px'>";

Comment: Only the script does not work. no mistakes

Comment: @Alina The script is working for me and also for the others. That's why you have to check why it doesn't work on your machine. So please check the given duplicate link how to get an error message of your PHP setup. After giving us this error message, we can help you hopefully.

Comment: It gives me an error! I changed the message

Comment: I this the only error message? Maybe your machine doesn't allow to get https-URLs via `file_get_contents()`. Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https

Comment: @TIIUNDER Can you give a complete version of my script?

Comment: @Alina I used YOUR script out of your question and it is working for me.