# Download Image From Steam Url PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to download image from url and add it to my wordpress page. Well everything is okay when url is like this :

```
www.domain.com/images/image.jpg
```

But I want to get image from steam market , and their image links look like this:

```
https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5gZKKkPLLMrfFqWdY781lteXA54vwxgbjrkc5ZD3wLNLGcFVrYl6GrAS2x7y7g8PvupidzyRmuCUl4H6IzkSpwUYbC6zHyEM/360fx360f
```

And when I call PHP function `file_get_contents($url);` It doesn't return image. 
So how can I retrieve image. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image link from Steam is using SSL. Using SSL in PHP requires a bit more setup than using a normal link. Replace the `https://` with `http://` in your image link and your problem should be solved.

```
file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5gZKKkPLLMrfFqWdY781lteXA54vwxgbjrkc5ZD3wLNLGcFVrYl6GrAS2x7y7g8PvupidzyRmuCUl4H6IzkSpwUYbC6zHyEM/360fx360f")
```

If you absolutely must use SSL to load the image, you can read how to do that on this other Stack Overflow question: [How to get file_get_contents() to work with HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think that was a problem :) !