# Save image from url to local System in php

Tags: php

Hi I am using the below code to download image from url but its not working when i am using this code

```
<?php
$imageUrl = 'https://cwsimages.ingramtest.com/cdsImages/imageloader?id=pBbFysOWRLJoSy4l4lbc+yLblU6JMuhKpze3XsQNO+njA3/XYRYbXSEYYsSqKXoiGD07duAyOSVXNUVLvxDqlMx15WtRQWJn3xC/twmM2s62tw+XgriCmEXBHawun03pQLBHXLuEQhNmCb8MC3ZMNH7pe5O76s18u/mgplf8YtU=';
@$rawImage = file_get_contents($imageUrl);
if($rawImage)
{
file_put_contents("images/".'dummy1.png',$rawImage);
echo 'Image Saved';
}
else
{
echo 'Error Occured';
}
?>
```

but if i changed the $imageUrl with this

```
$imageUrl = 'http://www.samsung.com/in/common/img/home/S2_pc.png';
```

it works, please suggest what is wrong in first url or can't we store image from https url

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https

Comment: i think in the above url $image_url you printing the image with image tag but not the whole image.
all you have to do is find the image regarding your query in the url and redirect the link to the image url then you can get the row image.

Comment: @dhaval Purohit Thanks for suggestion! but I am not printing with image tag. when you directly copy and paste the image url it will show image and i have to just download the that image in local system.

Comment: ohk wait a minute i will give you the solution @ManojGupta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the "images" you are using in the file_put_contents is not getting the path that where to save the file. try to make the images folder along with php file which having this code and see its working.

```
<?php
$imageUrl = 'https://cwsimages.ingramtest.com/cdsImages/imageloader?id=pBbFysOWRLJoSy4l4lbc+yLblU6JMuhKpze3XsQNO+njA3/XYRYbXSEYYsSqKXoiGD07duAyOSVXNUVLvxDqlMx15WtRQWJn3xC/twmM2s62tw+XgriCmEXBHawun03pQLBHXLuEQhNmCb8MC3ZMNH7pe5O76s18u/mgplf8YtU=';
@$rawImage = file_get_contents($imageUrl);
if($rawImage)
{
file_put_contents("images/".'dummy1.png',$rawImage);
echo 'Image Saved';
}
else
{
echo 'Error Occured';
}
?>
```

Comment: i have already created images folder in the same path where i have php file.  if i use the this url `code` $imageUrl = 'http://www.samsung.com/in/common/img/home/S2_pc.png'; then it work but if i used  `code` $imageUrl = 'https://cwsimages.ingramtest.com/cdsImages/imageloader?id=pBbFysOWRLJoSy4l4lbc+yLblU6JMuhKpze3XsQNO+njA3/XYRYbXSEYYsSqKXoiGD07duAyOSVXNUVLvxDqlMx15WtRQWJn3xC/twmM2s62tw+XgriCmEXBHawun03pQLBHXLuEQhNmCb8MC3ZMNH7pe5O76s18u/mgplf8YtU='; then its not working

Comment: it is working in my localhost @ManojGupta the same code of yours
if you are using the linux system then you have to first set the write permission in the images folder otherwise it is working with the windows.

Comment: I am using window 10 system. can it be some kind of authentication issue as its working the same code in your system and not in mine

Comment: so tell me how can i see that what the actual problem is.? @ManojGupta

Comment: this saved me so much time and work thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
$imageUrl = 'http://www.samsung.com/in/common/img/home/S2_pc.png';
if (!file_exists('folder_name')) 
{
    mkdir('folder_name', 0777, true);
}
$img_path="folder_name/S2_pc.png";
copy($imageUrl , $img_path);
echo $img_path;
```

Comment: i tried to use copy function but it's shwoing error: `code` Warning: copy(https://cwsimages.ingramtest.com/cdsImages/imageloader?id=pBbFysOWRLJoSy4l4lbc+yLblU6JMuhKpze3XsQNO+njA3/XYRYbXSEYYsSqKXoiGD07duAyOSVXNUVLvxDqlMx15WtRQWJn3xC/twmM2s62tw+XgriCmEXBHawun03pQLBHXLuEQhNmCb8MC3ZMNH7pe5O76s18u/mgplf8YtU=) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @Manoj Gupta : change your folder name with "folder_name". replace images in the place of folder_name.

Comment: I have already created the images folder and change folder_name with 'images'. I think if i am using  `code` $imageUrl = 'https://cwsimages.ingramtest.com/cdsImages/imageloader?id=pBbFysOWRLJoSy4l4lbc+yLblU6JMuhKpze3XsQNO+njA3/XYRYbXSEYYsSqKXoiGD07duAyOSVXNUVLvxDqlMx15WtRQWJn3xC/twmM2s62tw+XgriCmEXBHawun03pQLBHXLuEQhNmCb8MC3ZMNH7pe5O76s18u/mgplf8YtU='; it's not working . but if i using `code` $imageUrl = 'http://www.samsung.com/in/common/img/home/S2_pc.png'; then its working perfectly.

Comment: @Manoj Gupta : its work perfectly for also your url https://cwsimages.ingramtest.com/cdsI.....

Comment: I understand it should work but unfortunatly its not working.