# https php request - Not returning any data

Tags: php, curl, https, file-get-contents

I tried to hit the URL "https://nutraplanet.com" using php whereas I am not getting data from any request methods. Requesting you to please give me some solution to it.

Please, find one of my code as below:

```
<?php
$output= file_get_contents('https://nutraplanet.com/products/controlled-labs-orange-triad/');
echo $output;
?>
```

Even CURL doesn't helped me. Please, advise me on the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file\_get\_contents() work with HTTPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https)

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply on this Franz. But, I have tried that link which lead me to failure.

Comment: could you please provide any error messages you've encountered , and additional code you have tried?

Comment: hey you can do this using simple $.ajax request i have done and one this is just you need the content of the particular file yes

Comment: Sure, It doesn't threw me any error instead it gave me an empty response. Here is my another code.                                                      <?php
$url = 'https://nutraplanet.com/products/controlled-labs-orange-triad/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>

Comment: Hi Jaydip. Sounds helpful, Could you please share me a sample how it can be used. So, that I can try that.

Comment: so you got error something like when you using ajax request "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: No Jaydip, It threw me neither proper response nor any errors

Comment: try the given code! and also enabled the extension

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enabled this extension 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en 
in your browser

and try this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<button id="getData">Get Attendees</button>
<div id="div1">
</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#getData").click(function(){
    var name = $("#eventid").val();
    $.ajax({url: "https://nutraplanet.com/products/controlled-labs-orange-triad",
        method:"get",
         success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Jaydip, I am trying the code to be executed on a Rackspace server. So, what should be the procedure?

Comment: you can try in your local server

Comment: paste above code into in between body tag and also enabled the extension give above that's work