# file_get_contents failed to open stream: No error in

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Im trying to get a JSON response from a URL in PHP to just echo it out.
But its not working and gives me the error code:

> ...[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in...

So I googled a bit and find out that maybe `allow_url_fopen` in php.ini is switched off but in my case it is turned on (I checked it with phpinfo()).

My Code looks like this:

```
<?php
   $data = file_get_contents('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=myapikey');

   echo $data;
 ?>
```

A normal response of this site looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "source": "bbc-news",
  "sortBy": "top",
  "articles": [
    {
      "author": "BBC News",
      "title": "Houston reels as Storm Harvey bears down on Louisiana",
      "description": "The tropical storm makes landfall in the state after leaving large parts of Houston under water.",
      "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-41096565",
      "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/1024x576/p05dnlwm.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2017-08-30T14:56:39Z"
    },
    {
      "author": "BBC News",
      "title": "Houston's volunteer navy",
      "description": "Local volunteers are stepping up to help with search and rescue missions in Houston.",
      "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/world-us-canada-41092624/houston-s-volunteer-navy",
      "urlToImage": "https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/cpsprodpb/A77F/production/_97597824_houston-volunteer_300817_cps-bbc-2.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2017-08-30T05:23:59Z"
    },
    {
      "author": "BBC News",
      "title": "North Korea: 'Japan missile was first step in Pacific operation'",
      "description": "North Korea says a missile fired over Japan was the \"first step\" in military operations in the Pacific.",
      "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-41091563",
      "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/1024x576/p05dp42x.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2017-08-30T06:11:24Z"
    }, ...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'd really suggest using `curl`, as it's easier to configure and debug and much less buggy than `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I imagine it might be because it is an HTTPS request. Have you tried the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https

Comment: thats the answer I get: "openssl: no http wrapper: yes https wrapper: no wrappers: array ( 0 => 'php', 1 => 'file', 2 => 'data', 3 => 'http', 4 => 'ftp', 5 => 'compress.zlib', 6 => 'zip', )". Do I have to download curl ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need CURL. Try this. Don't forget to include your api key! You can just edit `$url`.

```
$url = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top';    
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json_response = curl_exec($ch);

echo($json_response);
```

Answer (score -1):

#### file_get_contents error:

***Use double quote when passing query string***

```
<?php

  $myapikey = "yourAPIKeyGoesHere";


   $data = file_get_contents("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=$myapikey");

   echo $data;
 ?>
```

#### See a live working demo of your code [here](http://vegasnewspaper.com/stack/news.php)

Comment: Doesn't change anything mate. Tried both

Comment: @AhmetKazaman your variable `$myapikey` was a string `myapikey` see my live example

Comment: I just changed the real apikey to myapikey to hide it from public. That shouldn't be the problem

Comment: Have you checked my live demo of your code provided in my answer? I edited my answer and provided a working live link. Thank you