# Bit Coin API for bit coin rate

Tags: php

I am using following code to get bitcoin price it is working off line but not working on server.

```
$api = "http://blockchain.info/ticker";
$json = file_get_contents($api);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$rate = $data["USD"]["15m"];
$symbol = $data["USD"]["symbol"];

echo $rate.$symbol;
?>
```

Comment: What is happening instead on your server? Is there any error message?

Comment: no there is no error .., localhost display value but server is not getting value

Comment: Have you tried using https://blockchain.info/ticker, and did you have a look into the servers error log?

Comment: Sounds like the firewall on the server is blocking the request.

Comment: yer there is an error in error log that is PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://blockchain.info/ticker): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/jatshakt/bitcoinbull.in/home.php on line 31

Comment: So, the main problem is that file_get_contents cannot work with the HTTPS url. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https for a solution - that will keep your code much shorter than the curl option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve when i use curl

```
$url = "http://blockchain.info/ticker";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($result, TRUE);
$rate = $data["USD"]["15m"];
$symbol = $data["USD"]["symbol"];
echo $rate.$symbol;
```

thanks to all for support..

Answer (score -1):

This method is not secure to perform a request to other server. You should use *curl* instead of **file_get_contents**. Btw, if still you want to keep this approach you can enable it in php.ini setting **allow_url_fopen** to **1**

Comment: What is the difference between file_get_contents and an approach using curl? Both gather data from an external ressource, both work to read data from a URL

Comment: Usually file_get_contents is used to read files from server, if a security hole appears in the app, an attacker could inject remote code (keeping in mind if the bug exist and file_get_contents is configured to accept http/s calls)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where curl helps you in avoiding some mysterious security holes that file_get_contents would leave open. Both just read files, they do not execute remote code, and if I can inject a URL to be opened into the application, both executions will call that URL

Comment: All depends about what the app is doing in the background. If we want to use file_get_contents we should do it just to read files from our web app without call any remote endpoint, for that, we need to use curl but if a developer is using file_get_contents to execute local php files or whatever then an attacker could inject remote code from url (as I said, always depends on the job the app is doing, and we need to put some problems to the attacker in each phase)

Comment: The result of file_get_contents is never ever executed, so you can never ever inject remote code. And both endpoints can be forged in the same way if the app contains an error