# file_get_contents for Instagram return empty response

Tags: php, browser, instagram, file-get-contents

When I use https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1 in my browser I get a nice json return ;))

When using it in a PHP script

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1');
$user = json_decode($response);
```

the return is always empty !!!

What I did wrong ? I have the same problem if I use Curl

Thank for your help...

Comment: but for my case both file_get_contents and curl is working fine,you can try same code on http://phpfiddle.org/ to be sure

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Yes... empty response !

Comment: And `var_dump($user)` shows what?

Comment: u_mulder : Nothing !

Comment: Always Sunny : Thanks for phpfiddle... that works! Could my server block responses?

Comment: I guess you need to enable `allow_url_fopen` in your php.ini config file

Comment: These networks generally do not _want_ you to scrape their content, and so they have measures in place to try and detect what you are doing. You should really rather be using the APIs they provide. (And if what you want to get is not available via API - then they most likely do not want you to be able to get that particular information in any automated way at all.)

Comment: Always Sunny : allow_url_fopen is ON

Comment: CBroe : I understand but for any instagram account it works! Something wrong on my server but I do not know what because I already use file_get_contents in other scripts with success!

Comment: Could be old [certificates](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) on your server.

Comment: @Chris its not a solution just sharing for debug purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47920994/1138192

Comment: Always Sunny : I have this return with your post :  openssl: yes http wrapper: yes https wrapper: yes wrappers: array ( 0 => 'https', 1 => 'ftps', 2 => 'compress.zlib', 3 => 'compress.bzip2', 4 => 'php', 5 => 'file', 6 => 'glob', 7 => 'data', 8 => 'http', 9 => 'ftp', 10 => 'phar', 11 => 'zip', )

Comment: that's weird, it should work for you then

Comment: It's not a problem with your code. For unknown reasons (might be number of requests from your ip, or your subnet,) instagram will redirect to login. Sometimes it even depends on the account you're trying to fetch (certain accounts would work, others would fail.)

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to scrape data from there json response like that (or with curl im not sure anymore), but after a time Instagram blocks your IP address and return an empty response.

EDIT: below the curl function I used

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
  $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close ($ch);

  if ($response_code == 200) {
    $insta_json = json_decode($server_output, true);

    if (is_array($insta_json) && isset( $insta_json['graphql']['user'] ) ) {

      $user = $insta_json['graphql']['user'];

      $data_array['user'] = [
          'name'        => isset($user['full_name']) ? $user['full_name'] : '',
          'description' => isset($user['biography']) ? $user['biography'] : '',
          'follow'      => isset($user['edge_follow']['count'])       ? $user['edge_follow']['count']       : '',
          'followed_by' => isset($user['edge_followed_by']['count'])  ? $user['edge_followed_by']['count']  : '',
          'profile_pic' => isset($user['profile_pic_url'])            ? $user['profile_pic_url']            : '',
      ];
      $data_array['images'] = [];

      if (isset($user['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'])) {

        $images = $user['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'];

        foreach ($images as $image) {

          $imageData = isset($image['node']) ? $image['node'] : false;

          if ($imageData) {

            $data_array['images'][] = [
                'liked'     => isset($imageData['edge_liked_by']['count'])          ? $imageData['edge_liked_by']['count']          : 0,
                'comment'   => isset($imageData['edge_media_to_comment']['count'])  ? $imageData['edge_media_to_comment']['count']  : 0,
                'image'     => isset($imageData['display_url'])                     ? $imageData['display_url']                     : '',
                'thumb'     => isset($imageData['thumbnail_resources'][2])          ? $imageData['thumbnail_resources'][2]['src']   : '',
                'shortcode' => isset($imageData['shortcode'])                       ? $imageData['shortcode']                       : '',
            ];
          }
        }
      } // End if isset edge_owner_to_timeline_media
    }// End check if user exist in array
  }// End check status code 200
```

Comment: Baracuda078 : Thanks for the try. That is very strange because using the Instagram url in the browser (for me) I get a response. If my IP was blocked the browser should return nothing!

Comment: Do you also send a valid user-agent with your request? And is yout cose running on your pc or on a webhost?

Comment: Baracuda078 : Running on webhost and if I use file_get_contents I do not need a user-agent

Comment: Then the IP of your webhost is probbely blocked, the funtion file_get_contents() indeed dont need a user agent but instagram checks your user agent to validate your a normal user

Comment: Baracuda078 : I just switch my IP to a mobile IP (different) and same thing! I checked with a new browser... same problem! Well this is a mystery!

Comment: How can you switch the IP address of your webhost? The request is going from your webhost not your device

Comment: Baracuda078 : I used my mobile connection which is different from my fiber connection

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't change the ip address of your webhost. And your webhost is making the request to instagram not your device. So the request from your webhost has to look like a normal request like from a device, so an user-agent is probely needed in the request headers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215820/discussion-between-chris-and-baracuda078).

Comment: I tried from another web site with a different IP (and DNS) and the same!!!