# Try to get feeds from Instagram with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, instagram, file-get-contents, var-dump

I need some help from you !

I'm using this URL to get feed informations from Instagram https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1

On a browser everything works fine ;))

But when using the code below from different web sites (hosting in Canada or France) I have a NULL response from var_dump !!! Instagram returns NULL

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1');
$result = json_decode($response, true);
var_dump($result);
```

If I use the same code with phpfiddle.org everything works fine even on my localhost !

Can someone try to run this script from a website (if he has one) to find out if the answer is also NULL ?

If not, is there an explanation that it doesn't work on my web sites and with me ?

By the way I already post this question but without a response to solve this problem ;((

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice [file\_get\_contents for Instagram return empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344092/file-get-contents-for-instagram-return-empty-response)

Comment: Hi Markus Zeller : I post it in a different way because I can not solve my problem since a few days ;(( May be somebody else has a response ;))