# How to read JSON file with PHP from instagram __a=1 page

Tags: php, json, curl, file-get-contents

I’m trying to call a URL and read its content using php.
when I place the url directly in the browser It works, but when I use php it returns empty string.
here’s my code:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1"
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$res= json_decode($json);
var_dump($res);
```

Does anyone have an idea why I can’t read the file with PHP?
Thank you,

Comment: There is a CORS issue no?

Comment: no, there's error just empty string

Comment: Your questions looks duplicate, I hope you find answers there

Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https